# Basic Malloc/Free

Tags: c, malloc, free

If I have a snippit of my program like this:

```
struct Node *node;
while(...){
    node = malloc(100);
    //do stuff with node
}
```

This means that every time I loop through the while loop I newly allocate 100 bytes that is pointed to by the node pointer right?

If this is true, then how do I free up all the memory that I have made with all the loops if I only have a pointer left pointing to the last malloc that happened?

Thanks!

Comment: In short, you can't. There's a reason for the rule of thumb "every `malloc` must be paired with a `free`".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please allocate exactly the size you need: `malloc(sizeof *node);` -- if you move to a 64-bit platform that doubles the size of all your members, your old 96-byte structure might take 192 bytes in the new environment.

If you don't have any pointers to any of the `struct Node`s you have created, then I don't think you should be allocating them with `malloc(3)` in the first place. `malloc(3)` is best if your application requires the data to persist outside the calling scope of the current function. I *expect* that you could re-write your function like this:

```
struct Node node;
while(...){
    //do stuff with node
}
```

or

```
while(...){
    struct Node node;
    //do stuff with node
}
```

depending if you want access to the last node (the first version) or not (the second version).

Of course, if you actually need those structures outside this piece of code, then you need to store references to them *somewhere*. Add them to a global list keeping track of `struct Node` objects, or add each one to the `next` pointer of the *previous* `struct Node`, or add each one to a corresponding `struct User` that refers to them, whatever is best for your application.

Comment: Even better: `node = malloc(sizeof *node);`.  (And to be clear, in `malloc(3)`, the `3` refers to section 3 of the Unix manual; it doesn't mean you're allocating 3 bytes.)

Answer (score 1):

If you set node = NULL before the loop and then use free(node) before node = malloc(100) you should be OK. You will also need to do a free(node) after the loop exits. But then again, it all depends on what "//do stuff with node" actually does. As others have pointed out, malloc(100) is not a good idea. What I would use is malloc(sizeof(*node)). That way, if the type of node changes, you don't have to change the malloc line.

Comment: This isn't safe outside of a single architecture where `sizeof(struct Node)` happens to be 100 bytes. You should *never* malloc a struct like that and instead use `malloc(sizeof(struct Node))`

Comment: @BrianRoach - I was just addressing his question, not his technique. In fact, I would prefer to use malloc(sizeof(*node)).

Comment: @BrianRoach, better yet to use `malloc(sizeof(*node)))`.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need the malloc'ed space at the end of one iteration anymore, you should free it right away.

To keep track of the allocated nodes you could save them in a dynamically growing list:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    int i;
    void *node;
    int prt_len = 0;
    void **ptrs = NULL;
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        node = malloc(100);
        ptrs = realloc(ptrs, sizeof(void*) * ++prt_len);
        ptrs[prt_len-1] = node;
        /* code */
    }
    for (i = 0; i < prt_len; i++) {
        free(ptrs[i]);
    }
    free(ptrs);
    return 0;
}
```

Note: You should probably re-think your algorithm if you need to employ such methods!

Otherwise see [sarnold's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7942178/basic-malloc-free/7942195#7942195).

Answer (score 0):

> then how do I free up all the memory that I have made with all the loops if I only have a pointer left pointing to the last malloc that happened?

You can't. You just created a giant [memory leak](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_leak).

You have to keep track of every chunk of memory you `malloc()` and `free()` it when you're done using it.

Answer (score 0):

You can not. You need to store all the pointer to free the memory. if you are saving those pointer somewhere then only you can free the memory.

Comment: Did you even read the other answers? Please write _you_, not _u_. Actually that applies to all aspects of life: If you don't have enough time to hit two more letters, don't write anything at all. Regardless _what_ you say, writing _u_ and _r_ makes to sound dumb.

Comment: @kay No hard feeling but use of "u" or "You" does not matter to me. And it should not to great minds as well because its proven by science that Mind never reads full spelling :)